# Error: Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net

I got this kind of error on live site whenever i upload image.
My site is hosted in Go daddy server.

please help  me to solve this error.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to talk with your host and ask if and how you can store uploaded images. They should give you the proper support.

Comment: Give write permission to the folder in the server where the Images are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably you might have to change your `permissions` `ASPNET` user or `NETWORK SERVICE` user. Try changing the permissions to the required folder that you need access to.

This articles about [How To: Use the Network Service Account to Access Resources in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx) and [Setting ASPNET (Network Service) Permissions](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/editor/installsettingaspnetpermissions.html) will provide you better understand about what need to be done.

Hope this helps.
Also you might have a look at [FileIOPermission Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx)